# How to arrange a list horizontally in HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am a very beginner in front-end developing but as far as I know 'li' items usually are laid out vertically. I used to use 'float' for horizontal layouts or Bootstraps 'col'. But this one uses 'ul' and 'li' meanwhile the code is brief and the result looks neat. Can anyone help me explain how it be achieved?

```
<div _ngcontent-c5="" class="col-sm-12">
<div _ngcontent-c5="" class="home_green_btn">
<ul _ngcontent-c5="" class="ng-tns-c5-1">
<li _ngcontent-c5="" class="head_green_btn"><a _ngcontent-c5="" class="ng-tns-c5-1" href="/Start-a-Check">Start a new check</a></li>
<li _ngcontent-c5="" class="head_green_btn"><a _ngcontent-c5="" class="ng-tns-c5-1" href="/resume_a_check"> Resume a check </a></li>
<li _ngcontent-c5="" class="head_green_btn"><a _ngcontent-c5="" class="ng-tns-c5-1" href="/Track-a-Check"> Track a check </a></li>
<li _ngcontent-c5="" class="head_green_btn"><a _ngcontent-c5="" class="ng-tns-c5-1" href="/Verify-a-Check">Verify a check</a></li></ul>
</div></div>
```

The live website is:  https://www.australiannationalcharactercheck.com.au/

Comment: Hi Oliver, welcome to SO! `.ng-tns-c5-1 { columns: 4 }` probably will do the trick... [CSS columns Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp)

Comment: @RenevanderLende Hooray that's really clear answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I've check out the source code and your `.head_green_btn` set `width: 60%`.

So if you want it to be in the same row with must be set to auto (or some percent value less than `100/(number of items)`)

Try this, i've tested it on chrome web console and it worked fine

```
<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="head_green_btn" style="width:auto;padding: 0 10px">
```

Comment: Thx for reply. but I think 'div' is block element, so if width is set to auto, will it be like stretch to the full width?